# Automatically delete TextBox and label if TextBox.Text = Empty on focus leave

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label, runtime

I have code that windows form starts with only 1 `Label` and 1 `TextBox`, when user starts to type on `TextBox1`,It creates a new TextBox and label down (also change location of 2 `Buttons` and change windows form size,It happens to max of 10 text box + 10 labels (side-side)
like:

```
(label1) Enter Name 1:  -  Textbox1 Imput 
(label2) Enter Name 2:  -  Textbox2 Imput 
(label1) Enter Name 3:  -  Textbox3 Imput 
...
```

It works great, but have a little "problem":

- my code creates a new `TextBox`/`Label` when user starts to type on last `TextBox`
- if the user stops on `Textbox7` for example, my code will have created `TextBox8` although it is not needed and does not contain text (is blank),
- therefore I would like `Delete` it automatically if the user tabs from `TextBox7` to `TextBox8` and leaves `TextBox8` (without entering text into tb8)

My code isn't working perfectly (will explain below) and if I click on `Button` that will verify if last `TextBox` text is `Empty` and if it is, will `Delete` text box and label at side and changes localization for `Buttons` and windows form size).

I have too many problems because `TextBox` 2 to 10 are created at runtime and its not possible to reference these "future" `TextBox` in code because I get error saying that it not exist in actual code.

Problem of `TextBox` and label `Delete` on `TextBox` focus leave when `TextBox.Text` is `Empty` is that it work great if I focus in another place in my focus using mouse click but if I press tab it `Delete` 2 `TextBox` and crash and return error: The index 12(can be any number) is out of range.

See my code to create new `TextBox` and labels + resize form and windows form size on txtNomecategoria_TextChanged:

```
public partial class cad_produto_acessorios_novo : Form
    {
        string testelogico;
        int c;
        int n = 1;
        int n2 = 25;
        int n3 = 65;
        int n4 = 57;
        int n5 = 152;
        public cad_produto_acessorios_novo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    private void txtNomecategoria_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (txtNomecategoria.TextLength > 1)
                {
                    n++;
                    if (n <= 1)
                    {
                        n = 2;
                    }
                    if (n >= 1 && n <= 2)
                    {
                        n2 = n2 + 30;
                        n3 = n3 + 30;
                        n4 = n4 + 30;
                        n5 = n5 + 30;
                        gpbCategoria.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(283, n4);
                        this.Height = n5;
                        btnApagar.Location = new Point(108, n3);
                        btnSalvar.Location = new Point(212, n3);

                        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                        txt.Name = "txtAcessorio" + n;
                        txt.Text = "";
                        txt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(189, 26);
                        txt.Location = new Point(87, n2);
                        testelogico = txt.Name;
                        gpbCategoria.Controls.Add(txt);

                        txt.TextChanged += new EventHandler(new_onchange);
                        txt.Leave += new EventHandler(erase_onLeave);

                        Label lbl = new Label();
                        lbl.Name = "lblAcessorio" + n;
                        lbl.Text = "Acessório Nº" + n + ":";
                        lbl.Location = new Point(4, n2 + 5);
                        gpbCategoria.Controls.Add(lbl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        n--;
                    }
                }
            }
```

note that it create 2 new event for new runtime created `TextBox`:

```
txt.TextChanged += new EventHandler(new_onchange);
txt.Leave += new EventHandler(erase_onLeave);
```

So here we go (create new `TextBox/Label` + resize windowsform,etc):

```
void new_onchange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cadeianovoscampos(sender as TextBox, e);
        }

private void cadeianovoscampos(TextBox _text, EventArgs e)
        {
            n++;

            if (_text.Text != null)
            {
                if (_text.Name == "txtAcessorio2")
                {
                    c = 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_text.Name == "txtAcessorio3")
                    {
                        c = 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (_text.Name == "txtAcessorio4")
                        {
                            c = 5;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (_text.Name == "txtAcessorio5")
                            {
                                c = 6;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (_text.Name == "txtAcessorio6")
                                {
                                    c = 7;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (_text.Name == "txtAcessorio7")
                                    {
                                        c = 8;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (_text.Name == "txtAcessorio8")
                                        {
                                            c = 9;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (_text.Name == "txtAcessorio9")
                                            {
                                                c = 10;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (n >= 1 && n <= c)
                {
                    n2 = n2 + 30;
                    n3 = n3 + 30;
                    n4 = n4 + 30;
                    n5 = n5 + 30;
                    gpbCategoria.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(283, n4);
                    this.Height = n5;
                    btnApagar.Location = new Point(108, n3);
                    btnSalvar.Location = new Point(212, n3);

                    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                    txt.Name = "txtAcessorio" + n;
                    txt.Text = "";
                    txt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(189, 26);
                    txt.Location = new Point(87, n2);
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Add(txt);
                    testelogico = txt.Name;
                    btnSalvar.Tag = 2;

                    txt.TextChanged += new EventHandler(new_onchange);
                    txt.Leave += new EventHandler(erase_onLeave);

                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Name = "lblAcessorio" + n;
                    lbl.Text = "Acessório Nº" + n + ":";
                    lbl.Location = new Point(4, n2 + 5);
                    gpbCategoria.Controls.Add(lbl);
                }
                else
                {
                    n--;
                }
            }
        }
```

And delete `TextBox/Labels` + resize windowsform,etc on Textbox focus leave (if Empty):

```
void erase_onLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cadeiaapagarcampos(sender as TextBox, e);
}



private void cadeiaapagarcampos(TextBox _text, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (_text.Text == "")
    {

        n--;
        if (gpbCategoria.Controls.Count < 4)
        {
        }
        else
        {

            if (n >= 1 && n <= 10)
            {
                n2 = n2 - 30;
                n3 = n3 - 30;
                n4 = n4 - 30;
                n5 = n5 - 30;
                int count = gpbCategoria.Controls.Count - 2;
                gpbCategoria.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(283, n4);
                this.Height = n5;
                btnApagar.Location = new Point(108, n3);
                btnSalvar.Location = new Point(212, n3);
                gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(_text);
                gpbCategoria.Controls.RemoveAt(count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its really to hard explain all, because code is big and its only possible solve problem if person know how code work. If I need add any additional information, only ask for that,  its near, but with your help  I can try to make it work.

---

Fast summary (can try hehe)

I want fix: 
1 - `Delete` current `TextBox` and side `Label` created on runtime if `Focus` leave current `TextBox` (if `.Text` is `Empty`): It works only if I Focus leave using mouse click on any part of windows form, but if i use tab on `TextBox` to `Focus` leave, it just not works, crash and return error.
2 - Add `Button` Save Function to check if last `TextBox` created is Empty or not and if it, it will `Delete` last created in runtime `TextBox/Label` (side-side), resize windows form and change `Button` localization (can use current `Delete` code that I developed to make these changes)

That's it, but I know that its big and hard to understand, I will try but its really big and its impossible understand/fix without know how entire code works.

Comment: Holy wall of text. Can you please try to narrow down your problem & question?

Comment: I think you're going about this in the wrong way. From what I can tell, you should probably be using a grid or list control to hold the values, then you can back them by collections with your data in it and you won't have to deal with these nested ifs and complicated eventing.

Comment: Create a List<Label> and a List<TextBox> at the Form level so you can keep references to what has been created, and know exactly how many of them there are.  It would make more sense to create a UserControl to encapsulate the Label and TextBox together into one unit.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Can you tell me more about that ? I just beginning on C#, never programmed anything, start with my first programming language (C# + .NEW on visual studio) just 2 weeks ago, so at moment i a noob on this. hehe. Anyway thanks

Comment: @felipeSalomao i used the approach Idle_Mind suggested. In my answer below you can see a List of textboxes `List<TextBox> textboxList = new List<TextBox>();` You can add another textbox to this list by calling the add Method: `textboxList.Add(newTextBox);` This way you can access the "future" textboxes in the list at runtime without getting an error that they do not exist.

Comment: i uploaded example code to help you get you going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Remove Textbox if text is empty

**Update:** I uploaded a [project with my code](https://github.com/surfmuggle/StackoverflowWinformQuestions/tree/master/DeleteTextbox) from below to github. You can open my project with [sharpdevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/) 4.3.

In the Event for your Textbox you can call/fire the TextBox_LeaveEvent method:

```
void TextBox_LeaveEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;     
    // add another textbox if this tb has text          
    if(textboxList.Count<5 && tb.Text.Length>0){
        var newTextBox = getNewTextBox(textboxList.Count);          
        textboxList.Add(newTextBox);
    } // remove textbox if it has no text
    else if(tb.Text.Length == 0){
        RemoveTextBox(tb);
    }                       
}
```

This does the following:

- if the current textbox (the sender that fired the event) has text it adds another textbox to a generic List of textboxes: `List<TextBox> textboxList = new List<TextBox>();`
- if the textbox has no text (`tb.Text.Length == 0`) it is removed from the list and from the windows form by calling RemoveTextBox

This is the method to remove a textbox

```
void RemoveTextBox(TextBox tb){
    // this.Controls.RemoveByKey(tb.Name);
    int tbIndex = this.Controls.IndexOf(tb);
    this.Controls[tbIndex].Dispose();
    textboxList.Remove(tb);         
}
```

This is the one to add the textbox dynamically to the form

```
TextBox getNewTextBox(int i)
{
    var tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(220, 90 + i * 24);
    tb.Name = "tb_" + i.ToString();
    tb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80,20);

    tb.Text = "textbox_"+i.ToString(); //String.Empty;          
    tb.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.TextBox_LeaveEvent);
    this.Controls.Add(tb);
    this.Refresh();
    return tb;
}
```

#### Some pointers regarding your code

From the code example above I assume that you could change your nested `if () { if (){} else { if}` to something simpler by using [if() else if()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/if) or by using switch (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/06tc147t%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) or [dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/switch)). As far i can tell from the code you gave you can probably remove a lot of code if you use a generic list of labels and textboxes.

```
string textBoxName = _text.Name;
switch (textBoxName)
{
    case "txtAcessorio2": 
        c= 3;
        break;
    case "txtAcessorio3":
        c=4;
        break;
    default:
        c=0;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Really thanks for code, will try it after (i will try understand)